# Creating a footer inside a bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, footer

I'm using this bootstrap template [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_temp_social&stacked=h) to create a page for my app.
In the center column (col-sm-7), where I will have a form, I want to create a footer/navbar/area at the bottom, that's fixed to the bottom, so that I can add buttons (ex. save, next, back).

I'm trying different things like a footer element, a bootstrap navbar with 'navbar-fixed-bottom' and a plain row with a div in it with a style where the bootom is 0 and the position is fixed, but none seem to be working correctly.

The problem is when I add any of these styles mentioned above, the width of the element fixed at the bottom doesn't stay within the center (col-sm-7) column. It ends up spanning the entire page or not enough. I just can't get it to be contained within the centered column

Any advice here to get something, anything, fixed at the bottom of just the center column so I can put buttons in it would be helpful!

Here is a sample of stuff I've tried so far

This one is with a footer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>    
    /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
    footer {
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
          </span>        
        </div>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> My Account</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container text-center">    
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 well">
      <div class="well">
        <p><a href="#">My Profile</a></p>
        <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="65" width="65" alt="Avatar">
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p><a href="#">Interests</a></p>
        <p>
          <span class="label label-default">News</span>
          <span class="label label-primary">W3Schools</span>
          <span class="label label-success">Labels</span>
          <span class="label label-info">Football</span>
          <span class="label label-warning">Gaming</span>
          <span class="label label-danger">Friends</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
        <p><strong>Ey!</strong></p>
        People are looking at your profile. Find out who.
      </div>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
    
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default text-left">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p contenteditable="true">Status: Feeling Blue</p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Like
              </button>     
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <p>John</p>
           <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <p>Bo</p>
           <img src="bandmember.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <p>Jane</p>
           <img src="bandmember.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <p>Anja</p>
           <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer style="bottom: 0; position: fixed" class="container-fluid text-center">
  <p>Footer Text</p>
</footer>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 well">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <p>Upcoming Events:</p>
        <img src="paris.jpg" alt="Paris" width="400" height="300">
        <p><strong>Paris</strong></p>
        <p>Fri. 27 November 2015</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Info</button>
      </div>      
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

this one is with a navbar, but it spans the entire width of the page. Not jsut the center column.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>    
    /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
    footer {
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
          </span>        
        </div>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> My Account</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container text-center">    
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 well">
      <div class="well">
        <p><a href="#">My Profile</a></p>
        <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="65" width="65" alt="Avatar">
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p><a href="#">Interests</a></p>
        <p>
          <span class="label label-default">News</span>
          <span class="label label-primary">W3Schools</span>
          <span class="label label-success">Labels</span>
          <span class="label label-info">Football</span>
          <span class="label label-warning">Gaming</span>
          <span class="label label-danger">Friends</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
        <p><strong>Ey!</strong></p>
        People are looking at your profile. Find out who.
      </div>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
    
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default text-left">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p contenteditable="true">Status: Feeling Blue</p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Like
              </button>     
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <p>John</p>
           <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <p>Bo</p>
           <img src="bandmember.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <p>Jane</p>
           <img src="bandmember.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <p>Anja</p>
           <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div style="border: 1px solid black;" class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom"><button>save</button></div>
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 well">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <p>Upcoming Events:</p>
        <img src="paris.jpg" alt="Paris" width="400" height="300">
        <p><strong>Paris</strong></p>
        <p>Fri. 27 November 2015</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Info</button>
      </div>      
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want to use javascript?

Comment: since Bootstrap is being used, you can try `scrollspy` and `affix` via data-attributes and it works like a charm

Answer (score 4):

First you need to understand the Basic structure , you don't need to put the footer in `-col` classes , take look at the structure

[image]

In standard case you can add your code like this way

```
<header>
<nav>
    <!-- Put the navbar here -->
</nav>
</header><!-- Header -->

<section>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-3">

        </div><!-- .left items like my profile etc.. -->

        <div class="col-sm-7">

        </div><!-- . main content section here-->

        <div class="col-sm-2">

        </div><!-- /. upcomming section will be here -->

    </div><!-- /.row -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->
</section> <!-- /.content section -->

<footer>

</footer><!-- footer always stay at bottom -->
```

i have change your code like the way

```css
header,
.full-width {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
footer {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a> 
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Messages</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
            <div class="form-group input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> 
              </button>
              </span>
            </div>
          </form>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> My Account</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section class="full-width">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 well">
          <div class="well">
            <p><a href="#">My Profile</a>
            </p>
            <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="65" width="65" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
          <div class="well">
            <p><a href="#">Interests</a>
            </p>
            <p> <span class="label label-default">News</span>  <span class="label label-primary">W3Schools</span>  <span class="label label-success">Labels</span>  <span class="label label-info">Football</span>  <span class="label label-warning">Gaming</span> 
              <span class="label label-danger">Friends</span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="alert alert-success fade in"> <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
            <p><strong>Ey!</strong>
            </p>
            People are looking at your profile. Find out who.</div>
          <p><a href="#">Link</a>
          </p>
          <p><a href="#">Link</a>
          </p>
          <p><a href="#">Link</a>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="panel panel-default text-left">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p contenteditable="true">Status: Feeling Blue</p>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Like</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="well">
                <p>John</p>
                <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <div class="well">
                <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="well">
                <p>Bo</p>
                <img src="bandmember.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <div class="well">
                <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="well">
                <p>Jane</p>
                <img src="bandmember.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <div class="well">
                <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="well">
                <p>Anja</p>
                <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <div class="well">
                <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 well">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <p>Upcoming Events:</p>
            <img src="paris.jpg" alt="Paris" width="400" height="300">
            <p><strong>Paris</strong>
            </p>
            <p>Fri. 27 November 2015</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Info</button>
          </div>
          <div class="well">
            <p>ADS</p>
          </div>
          <div class="well">
            <p>ADS</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <button>save</button>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What happens if i already have a footer and want to add a footer inside the `col-`? My friend this is not an answer.

Comment: explaining my downvote, bootstrap has `scrollspy` and `affix` plugins just for handling problems such as this one.

Answer (score 1):

add 2 styles to footer tag

```
<style>
footer {
    width: 95%;
    z-index: 100;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I modified your code may be it can help you.

Go through this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FAO2A1UB5M3E)

CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>    
    /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
    footer {
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
          </span>        
        </div>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> My Account</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container text-center">    
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 well">
      <div class="well">
        <p><a href="#">My Profile</a></p>
        <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="65" width="65" alt="Avatar">
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p><a href="#">Interests</a></p>
        <p>
          <span class="label label-default">News</span>
          <span class="label label-primary">W3Schools</span>
          <span class="label label-success">Labels</span>
          <span class="label label-info">Football</span>
          <span class="label label-warning">Gaming</span>
          <span class="label label-danger">Friends</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
        <p><strong>Ey!</strong></p>
        People are looking at your profile. Find out who.
      </div>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7" style="position:relative;padding-bottom:10px;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default text-left">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p contenteditable="true">Status: Feeling Blue</p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Like
              </button>     
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <p>John</p>
           <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <p>Bo</p>
           <img src="bandmember.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <p>Jane</p>
           <img src="bandmember.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <p>Anja</p>
           <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center" style="background-color:#404040;color:#fff;position:absolute;bottom:0px;">
          Footer
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 well">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <p>Upcoming Events:</p>
        <img src="paris.jpg" alt="Paris" width="400" height="300">
        <p><strong>Paris</strong></p>
        <p>Fri. 27 November 2015</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Info</button>
      </div>      
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

You just need to change position of your centered div to relative and make a div with position absolute inside of that and fixed it to bottom.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you need fixed footer that always visible in the bottom of window and has width as the central column has.
My idea is to use predefined bootstrap class `navbar-fixed-bottom` with footer inside:

```html
<nav class="navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-3">
        <footer>
          <p>Footer Text</p>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

here is a snippet:

```css
footer {
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px;
      margin: 0 -15px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
          </span>        
        </div>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> My Account</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<nav class="navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-3">
        <footer class="text-center">
          <p>Footer Text</p>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container text-center">    
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 well">
      <div class="well">
        <p><a href="#">My Profile</a></p>
        <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="65" width="65" alt="Avatar">
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p><a href="#">Interests</a></p>
        <p>
          <span class="label label-default">News</span>
          <span class="label label-primary">W3Schools</span>
          <span class="label label-success">Labels</span>
          <span class="label label-info">Football</span>
          <span class="label label-warning">Gaming</span>
          <span class="label label-danger">Friends</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
        <p><strong>Ey!</strong></p>
        People are looking at your profile. Find out who.
      </div>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
    
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default text-left">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p contenteditable="true">Status: Feeling Blue</p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Like
              </button>     
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <p>John</p>
           <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <p>Bo</p>
           <img src="bandmember.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <p>Jane</p>
           <img src="bandmember.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <p>Anja</p>
           <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>     

</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 well">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <p>Upcoming Events:</p>
        <img src="paris.jpg" alt="Paris" width="400" height="300">
        <p><strong>Paris</strong></p>
        <p>Fri. 27 November 2015</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Info</button>
      </div>      
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

it's too complicated when i copy your snippet this is the simple code i wrote, maybe you like it.

```css
section{
height:700px;
background:#ccc;
position:relative;
z-index:20;
margin-bottom:100px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.navbar{
margin-bottom:0;}  

</style>
  </head>
<body>
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
          </span>        
        </div>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> My Account</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>  
</header>
  
  
<section class="container">
 your content here, it's along content i believe 
</section>
  
  
 <footer style="bottom: 0; position: fixed" class="container-fluid text-center">
  Footer Text
</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

**I think the easiest way for you to achieve that is to add the below to your footers style.**

```
left: 0;
width: 100%;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use bootstrap's `affix` and `scrollspy`. Remember to pass your custom CSS to affix class to set the style you want.

```css
.affix {
      bottom: 0;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color:#000;
      z-index:9999;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>    
    /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
    footer {
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".save">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
          </span>        
        </div>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> My Account</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container text-center">    
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 well">
      <div class="well">
        <p><a href="#">My Profile</a></p>
        <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="65" width="65" alt="Avatar">
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p><a href="#">Interests</a></p>
        <p>
          <span class="label label-default">News</span>
          <span class="label label-primary">W3Schools</span>
          <span class="label label-success">Labels</span>
          <span class="label label-info">Football</span>
          <span class="label label-warning">Gaming</span>
          <span class="label label-danger">Friends</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
        <p><strong>Ey!</strong></p>
        People are looking at your profile. Find out who.
      </div>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
    
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default text-left">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p contenteditable="true">Status: Feeling Blue</p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Like
              </button>     
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <p>John</p>
           <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <p>Bo</p>
           <img src="bandmember.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <p>Jane</p>
           <img src="bandmember.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <p>Anja</p>
           <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="150"><button>save</button><button>edit</button><button>delete</button></div>          
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 well">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <p>Upcoming Events:</p>
        <img src="paris.jpg" alt="Paris" width="400" height="300">
        <p><strong>Paris</strong></p>
        <p>Fri. 27 November 2015</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Info</button>
      </div>      
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix whole section at the bottom then footer will remain in the column.

CSS:

```
.footer-outer{ 
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0; 
    left:0; 
    z-index:1000; 
} 


<section class="footer-outer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <footer>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following code for your second template, one with the navbar.

```
    <style>
    .navbar.navbar-fixed-bottom {
        width: 95%;
        margin: auto;
    }
    </style>
```