# CSS position fixed affects responsive design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm facing responsive issue when I add `position:fixed` for the nav-tabs.

[image]

The above image is actual view.There are 2 two iframes im using. left side is the nav-tab (text-bucket,image-bucket....). middle it is a slider. right side is another frame.

HTML of nav-tab:-

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Text Bucket</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Image Bucket</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Table Bucket</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">View Selected Items</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" class="prev" href="#preview">Preview</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to make the whole nav-tab sectiono fixed, so I have added `position:fixed`.

CSS:-

```
.nav {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul.nav-tabs {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    /* width: 48%; */
}
.nav>li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.nav-tabs>li {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

[image]

From the above image u can see the preview tab stays out when I use middle slider dragging to left. This is because of position:fixed. if I remove position fixed it is working correctly the preview tab will come down responsively.

Any solution for this? I need the tabs top be `position:fixed` and when I drag the slider left, the tabs should automatically come down one by one.

Comment: pls provide more html code or give link to jsfiddle snippet

Comment: We need to see the complete css for your `nav` `nav-tabs`.

Comment: @Banzay i have update with more code.

Comment: @WhiteHox  sorry, i cant give u this in jsfiddle because i have to add more js and links. sorry for my inconvinence.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove position:fixed in small devices using media Queries

```
@media (max-width:992px){
  ul.nav-tabs { position:static; }
}
```

Comment: im not gonna look into small devices bro, there is a slider in middle(splitter) if i drag to left side , the tabs should come automatically come down one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set .nav-tabs width, like you set in in comment. If you want it in the same place, you can try somethin like this:

```
.nav-tabs {
    left: 5%;
    width: 44%
}
```

Or set

```
.nav-tabs { 
left:0; 
width: 49%; 
padding-left: 50px; 
background:none;
}
```

where padding left is your icon.

I don't completely understand your iframe concept, so correct me if this solution is not working for you.

Comment: sorry bro, applying width will not work. i have already tried.  Any way thanks bro. I will let u know if i got solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

I think your problem is this one: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9zzf87ex/)

If you have an element with "fixed" position, It will be out of the html flow so it will be unaffected by whatever other element position (like your panel at the right side)

The easiest way to solve it, imo, is with a bit of jquery.

Just get the width of any element of your left side that gets the 100% width of the his container (Your slider maybe?) and aply this width to your fixed element. make the event on page load and on resize so it will recalculate if the user manually changes the browser width.

Like this:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('.nav-tabs').outerWidth($('.stuff').width());
}).resize();
```

where `stuff` is the element on your left side as I said before.

Chek it out here: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/t6pyLuw6/)

Comment: im not gonna resize my window, im gonna drag the slider(splitter in middle of 2iframes) to left side.

Comment: but some how u the one who understood my issue. please give me solution.

Comment: I gave you the solution. add an element with the width you need to set for you `nav` (make it NOT fixed) and use my solution. You can even make the element invisible with `display:none`

Comment: With the info you provided on your question there's not anything else we can do to help. make a fiddle (with your js and links. it can be done)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure styled Bootstrap solution:
[jsfiddle.net/6n0fctpc/](https://jsfiddle.net/6n0fctpc/)

The snippet has the same code:

```css
.right, .left {
  height:200px;
  background-color:orange;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.left {background-color:green;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Text Bucket</a></li>
              <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Image Bucket</a></li>
              <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Table Bucket</a></li>
              <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">View Selected Items</a></li>
              <li><a data-toggle="tab" class="prev" href="#preview">Preview</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 left">left </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 right">right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 left">left </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 right">right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 left">left </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 right">right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 left">left </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 right">right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41096008/4206079) you'll find my solution for similar issue for the narrowed fixed footer.